# "monitor brightness down" key resets brightness before lowering it

Tags: nvidia, dell, laptop, brightness, backlight

My monitor brightness down key resets my brightness before lowering it, effectively leaving me at near max brightness. I do not experience any problems with the brightness up key.

I'm using a Dell XPS 15 laptop with an NVIDIA gpu. Its a fresh install of Ubuntu 14.04 with gnome 3 and it worked fine with 13.04 with unity. I added `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"` to my grub file (since this was the solution in 13.04 and I've added

```
Section "Device"
        Identifier  "card0"
        Driver      "intel"
        Option      "Backlight"  "intel_backlight"
        BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"

EndSection
```

to `/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/20-intel.conf`

I can change my brightness with a workaround but I would like to use the normal brightness controls.

**Edit:** I removed the `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"` part from my grub and changed it back to "quiet splash".

My brightness down key keeps on resetting the brightness. I've mapped another key to the same keycode (`224`, monitor brightness down) and it works fine! Why is the normal brightness down key not working?

When I open a virtual terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>) and press the brightness down key I get a time stamp with the text `ACPI: failed to switch the brightness` (which is expected) and the brightness resets anyway (which is unexpected).

Meaning that the resetting of the brightness isn't linked to the "brightness down" command under the key but linked to the key itself. Some secondary command, bug or something else.This is confirmed by disabling the brightness controls using dconf-editor. Even after disabling these controls the brightness down button resetted the brightness.

Comment: You don't mention what version you *are* using..

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm using 14.04. it's a fresh install.

Comment: I also have a dell, and I don't have this problem, but maybe the bios and the os are trying to change the level at the same time? What about disabling the key binding temporarily, and test the result?

Comment: `xbacklight -inc 20` is this command working?

Comment: xbacklight is working just fine. binding the `brightness down` function to another key is working as well. it's just the normal key that's not working. @davidbaumann: I'll test that

Comment: urg....xbindkeys isn't seeing my fn function keys....unless you know a way to unbind the brightness function key I can't do it.

Comment: My question was: If you unbind the brightness keys, what happens?

Comment: oke, I've disabled the multimedia keys using dconf-editor and disabling org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys.active. When I press the brightness down key my brightness resets. All other control over the brightness using the keyboard is gone.

Comment: Try changing brightness using your brightness keys, then in terminal `dmesg | tail` and post result.  It sounds familiar--BQC invalid method or something

Comment: it outputs: `[  845.837557] ACPI: Failed to switch the brightness`

Answer (score 0):

After you installed in terminal with

> sudo apt-get install xrand*

Goto dash-symbol at top of unity-bar (left side)

a) - then type "sys" into the input-line for text -

b) - there you can see the symbol for keyboard click on it -

c) - then you can define the appropriate what-to-do-for-you by hitting
the certain key on your desktop

d) - you can add some code into the desription of your certain 
key-to-define-your-wish-to-perform-your-command

e) - by this you can add too the command for to dim xrand the proper values suiting to your screen or to your graphics-card (due to your voltage of your electricity cable at home)

Here is a description about the xrand-command and you only would need to pick out of this the correct display-size of your graphics-card.

http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-change-display-resolution-settings-using-xrandr.html

Cheers.

Comment: Hi, I get that you want me to set a shortcut to the brightness down key with the xrand brightness down command. problem is that the brightness will reset whenever the button is pressed (even if I disable all command and functions of that key). So with your solution the following happens in quick succession: 1) brightness resets to full brightness. 2) brightness goes down due to xrand. (you could have read this at the bottom of my question but oh well.) I've long since discovered why my pc does this. The command given by the bios doesn't work with this version of ubuntu.

Comment: and since the bios will give that command every time that key is pressed I can't disable it easily. I've long since circumvented the problem by simply binding the brightness down command to a different key. I could make a handler for the brightness down command from the bios but I decided it would be to much of a bother. btw, reading a question helps to give an accurate answer (I'm using gnome, the bug is linked to that specific key and not the command, xrand has been suggested in the comments and it didn't work.) but thanks for trying to help.